# What is causing this strange output when using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, foreach, infinite-loop, scheduledexecutorservice

I am creating a hashmap that sums the trading volume of a collection of stocks as the trades occur in real-time.  I would like to "re-set" the volume hashmap every minute and sum the next set of volumes over the following minute, repeating this process over the entire trading day.

I have this so far:

```
Double vol; 
String mS;
Map<String, Double> volMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
Map<String, Double> volMapAdd = new HashMap<String, Double>();

     for (Trade trade : events) {     //this iterates through an Array of stock symbols
         vol = trade.getSizeAsDouble();  //this method calls the volume of the iterated symbol
         mS = trade.getEventSymbol();  //this method calls the stock symbol for the associated trade
         if (mS != null)               //checks if null
            volMap.put(mS, vol);          //then adds the volume and symbol to a Hashmap
         if (mS != null)   
            volMapAdd.putIfAbsent(mS,vol);  //this creates a baseline for the summation Hashmap
         if (vol !=null & volMapAdd.get(mS) !=null)
            volMapAdd.computeIfPresent(mS,(k,v) -> v + vol); //this creates the summation Hashmap

         System.out.println(volMapAdd.entrySet());
         executorService.schedule(new Runnable( ) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("initiating");
                volMapAdd.putAll(volMap);     //re-sets the summation Hashmap to volMap current state
                System.out.println(volMapAdd.entrySet() + " after reset");
            }
        }, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    while (!Thread.interrupted())            //creates an endless loop
        Thread.sleep(1000);
```

The program runs fine, adding up the volumes for the selected symbols over the initial 30 second delay, then runs through the run() method and "re-sets" the summation Hashmap volMapAdd.  But after that I get multiple instances of "initializing" being printed to the console, indicating that the run() method is being called many times.  I don't know if there is something strange happening with different threads, or if the initial for each loop is causing the run() method to be called multiple times.  Any help sorting this out would be much appreciated.  Also, I'm very very new to java (and programming in general).  Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not a strange output. For each `trade` in `events`, you're scheduling a new task.

Comment: Yes!  I realized that after I posted and was driving in the car (of course).  I was thinking, however, that even if I moved it out of the for each trade in events, it would still be looped by the while (!Thread.interrupted()).  I think I should take out the while loop and encapsulate everything I want to loop into separate scheduleatfixedrate methods.  Thank you!